# ajax onreadystatechange function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've ajax oop script which is working perfectly but doesn't callback onreadystatechange function. here is code =>

```
function AjaxConstruct(method,file,params){
    this.method = method;
    this.file = file;
    this.params = params;
    this.http = false;
}

AjaxConstruct.prototype.ajax = function(){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    this.http = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    this.http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} 
if (this.http){
this.http.open(this.method,this.file,true);
if (this.method==="POST"){
    this.http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
}
this.http.send(this.params);
this.http.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.http.readyState==4 && this.http.status==200){
        alert("yeah");
    }
};
}
};
```

it doesn't callback onreadystatechange anonymous function , how can be it solved ? thanks :)

invoking method like this =>

```
var ajax = new AjaxConstruct("POST","filename","params");
ajax.ajax();
```

but onreadystatechange doesn't called :(

Comment: How do you know it is not called? I think it is, but accessing `this.http.readyState` will throw an error, since inside the callback, `this` does not refer to your instance. Have a look at the console for errors.

Comment: it is not called , because it is sending params to mysql database and everything is working except alerting result , i do not know how to solve it

Comment: That's what I'm saying: Accessing `this.http.readyState` will result in an error and therefore the alert won't be shown, but the function will still be called. Just use `this.readyState` etc or assign the `XMLHTTPRequest` object to a local variable and use that instead of `this.http`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the callback is called, but accessing `this.http.readyState` will throw an error, since inside the callback, `this` does not refer to your instance.

Have a look at the console for errors.

Just use `this.readyState` or assign the `XMLHTTPRequest` object to a local variable and use that instead of `this.http`.

Learn more about [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: now I've debugged with fire bug , when i it is going to onreadystatechange function it is making step out